# Booting ubuntu from a mac

Tags: boot, mac, firewire

First note: I AM NOT USING A USB HARD DRIVE!!! I AM USING FIREWIRE!!!

I am wondering how to boot ubuntu from an external hard drive on a mac.

When I hold option when booting up, only one partition (the one I use for backing things up) shows up.

I know it is hard to boot from a usb, but again, I am using firewire 800.

So how do I boot up ubuntu?

SIDE NOTE: For some unknown reason, ONCE AND ONLY ONCE when booting up my computer, it booted to ubuntu (wha???) and everything worked normal. I have not been able to repeat this, and I have no idea how it happened.

Comment: FYI ...  You can dual boot a Mac if your approach doesn't pan out ... good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research, I found a nice way to boot Ubuntu.

Follow the instructions [**here**](http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/). It worked very well for me.